# Rust minimalist way to round robin an integer in a specific range

Tags: rust

Given a number `N` in a range `R = [min, max)` and an offset `O`, what is the most minimalist way (less code) to round robing `N + O` inside `R`.

Assume both `N`, `R`, `min`, `max` and `O` integers.

For example:

## Case 1

```
N = 5
R = [-10, 10)
O = 5

Answer = -10
```

## Case 2

```
N = 5
R = [-10, 10)
O = 20

Answer = 5
```

## Case 3

```
N = -10
R = [-10, 10)
O = -1

Answer = 9
```

Comment: Is the third case right? `10` is not contained in `[-10, 10)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```rust
fn clamp_round(n: i32, r: std::ops::Range<i32>) -> i32 {
    (n + r.start).rem_euclid(r.end - r.start) + r.start
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(clamp_round(5 + 5, -10..10));
    dbg!(clamp_round(5 + 20, -10..10));
    dbg!(clamp_round(-10 + -1, -10..10));
    dbg!(clamp_round(5 + 5, 100..110));
    dbg!(clamp_round(5 + 20, 100..110));
    dbg!(clamp_round(-10 + -1, 100..110));
}
```

Note that we use `rem_euclid` here to handle negative values in the way we want.

Output:

```
[src/main.rs:6] clamp_round(5 + 5, -10..10) = -10
[src/main.rs:7] clamp_round(5 + 20, -10..10) = 5
[src/main.rs:8] clamp_round(-10 + -1, -10..10) = 9
[src/main.rs:9] clamp_round(5 + 5, 100..110) = 100
[src/main.rs:10] clamp_round(5 + 20, 100..110) = 105
[src/main.rs:11] clamp_round(-10 + -1, 100..110) = 109
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6de6519d04920a6a539dd39428426ffb)

Comment: Strictly speaking, the question says that `N` is in the range: so your final three examples are invalid (though perhaps this behaviour is still acceptable to the OP).

Comment: @eggyal I don't think the additional restriction will simplify the code further so I went for the generic solution which handles any number.